# Can we import .sql file into HSQL database?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, hsqldb

In my Java desktop application, i am using MySQL server for database operations but for some reasons i want to switch my application to work with HSQL database. My question is can we import the .sql file exported from MySQL into HSQL database to get the database structure as it is into HSQL database ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible using a MySQL dump of your database, but you've to be carefull of some MySQL compatibilities : http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/management-chapt.html#mtc_compatibility_mysql.

Maybe some databases tools : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_database_tools, or the http://hsqldb.org/doc/util-guide/transfer-tool-chapt.html can do the trick.

Comment: Hello Mr. guiton,thank you for reply,i have exported my MySQL database to a .sql file but how should i import that file into HSQL database ? I have read the links suggested by you but not getting the exact idea of transfer tool.

Comment: See HSQLDB's SqlTool docs http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/util-guide/sqltool-chapt.html#sqltool_nonint-sect